# -bash: use:command not found Mac 5.18 perl

Tags: bash

Mac -bash: use: command not found mac Darwin 5.18 perl modules installed use, version, base

Comment: Please provide more detail.  What is your question?  What are you attempting to do when you see this error?

Comment: Trying to run `perl` code with `bash` in most cases will not work out so well.

Answer (score 1):

This suggests that your script is missing the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line that identifies the appropriate interpreter.  A Perl script should begin with something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

Without this as the first line of the file, your default shell (here, `bash`) will be invoked, and thus choke on Perl syntax.

If for some reason you cannot modify the script, simply invoke it like this:

```
perl ./myscript
```